# How does not disabling local interrupts in interrupt handler(which acquire lock) could lead to double-acquire deadlock?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

In Linux Kernel Development book (Robert Love), It is mentioned that :

> we must disable local interrupts before obtaining spinlock in
>   interrupt handler. Otherwise it is possible for an interrupt handler
>   to interrupt kernel code while the lock is held and attempt to
>   re-acquire the lock. Which finally can lead to double-acquire
>   deadlock.

Now my doubt is:

1. In general, doesn't `do_IRQ()` disables local interrupt ?
2. And if lock is acquire, it means that`preempt_count` variable is not zero, which makes that no other handler should get chance, as kernel is not `preempt_safe`. So how other interrupt handler can work in this situation ?

Answer (score 2):

First, the `do_IRQ()` function dosn't disable the local interrupt, but some function written in assembly language does, which is the interrupt entrance. And later, before executing the interrupt function registering by `request_irq()`, in function `handle_IRQ_event()` a flag which also pass by `request_irq()` is compare with `IRQF_DISABLED` to determine whether we should enable the local interrupt when executing the interrupt function. So the answer to your question one is depending on the flags that you pass to the `request_irq()` function.

Second, `preempt_count` just means for kernel preemption in process context, but not for interrupt. To avoid interrupt handlers be executed in UP, the only way is involving the `irqs_disable()`. When the `preempt_count` is zero, it's said that the kernel can safely does the process switch, otherwise not.